# Wise to grab uploaded files contents from its temporary location?

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I'm building a system, where user can upload a file as data (not for permanent storing, just the contents). Now I'm wondering whether it's wise to grab the files contents from its temporary location provided by PHP, like this:

```
file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])
```

Works fine on localhost, but I'm afraid there could be some permission-issues etc on hosting? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please stop signing your questions. We already know who you are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *only chance* for you to get the data is by reading the file given in the `'tmp_name'` variable. There's no other way to do it. PHP puts the file there for you, so you can be assured it's readable. If it's not, the server configuration is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the location of the uploaded files with the [`upload_tmp_dir`](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.upload-tmp-dir) directive, so you know that you won't get any permission errors. However, you cannot set this at run-time using [ini_set](http://php.net/ini_set).

If you want to move the uploaded file to a new location, you should use [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file).

Answer (score 1):

That's the generally accepted way to do it. Assuming the upload_tmp_dir location is one that is readable/writable by the world (which it would have to be to accept the upload) you will be able to read it once it is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you could pretty much guarantee the files in the tmp directory will be alive at least until that PHP process dies, however i'd use `fopen()` rather than file_get_contents.

Regarding the permissions, that PHP process will have written the file there from the headers so you can 100% guarantee the same process also has read access.

Comment: Strictly speaking you can't guarantee that it has read perms just because it has write perms.